# Why is my mobile navigation bar experiencing this occurance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem is the following, when I size down my browser to 1240px, open the mobile menu and then close it down and resize my browser to resolution higher than 1240px my whole navigation bar disappears. I've tinkered with this for some time now and I can't fix it. My biggest problem is that I'm not sure whether the problem is on the JS side or the CSS Media queries side.

```js
$('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
  $('.container li:not(:first-child)').toggle();
  $('.container li:nth-child(8)').toggle();
});
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

body {
  /*background-color: #ece8e5;*/
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 550;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #151719;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container>li {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #151719;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.space {
  flex: 1;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.logIn,
.signUp {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1240px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .container>li {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1240px) {
  .container li:not(:nth-child(1)) {
    display: none;
  }
  .container .dropdown {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class='navigation'>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="container">
      <li class='dropdown'><img class='dropdownImg' src='{{ url("storage/uploads/icons/dropdown.png") }}'></li>
      <li><a href="">Images</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Albums</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Tags</a></li>

      <li><a href="">Upload</a></li>

      <li><a href="">Admin Panel</a></li>

      <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li class='space'></li>

      <li class="logIn">Log In</li>
      <li class='signUp'>Sign Up</li>


      <li class='logOut'><a href="">Logout</a></li>
      @endauth
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: In your css you are hiding your `li` tags for resolutions larger than `1240px`(except the first one). so what is your problem?

Comment: @pooyan he stated when resizing the screen larger than 1240px after the initial breakpoint, the nav bar would not return.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate this issue. [See my CodePen to see how it behaves](https://codepen.io/codespent/full/zagZmo/), but I don't have any issue so possibly a localized issue?

Comment: Resize to to below 1240px, open the menu, close it and resize it back to over 1240px. The <li> are no more visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem was in your `container li:not(:nth-child(1))` which set to none. and your script function trigger the other li to hidden when the screen is larger. So I use toggleClass to prevent this. Here your snippet right now:

```js
$('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
  $('.container li').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

body {
  /*background-color: #ece8e5;*/
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 550;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: #151719;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container>li {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #151719;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.space {
  flex: 1;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.logIn,
.signUp {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1240px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .container>li {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1240px) {
  .container li:first-child { /* exclude */
    display:block;
  }
  .container li { /* this should none */
    display: none;
  }
  
  .container li.active { /* toggleClass */
    display: block;
  }
  .container .dropdown {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class='navigation'>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="container">
      <li class='dropdown'><img class='dropdownImg' src='{{ url("storage/uploads/icons/dropdown.png") }}'></li>
      <li><a href="">Images</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Albums</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Tags</a></li>

      <li><a href="">Upload</a></li>

      <li><a href="">Admin Panel</a></li>

      <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li class='space'></li>

      <li class="logIn">Log In</li>
      <li class='signUp'>Sign Up</li>


      <li class='logOut'><a href="">Logout</a></li>
      @endauth
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please don't make us play spot the difference. Explain what you changed and why it fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your suggestion, I've edit the answer. Have a good day!